# Pyspark - Create Timestamp from Date and Hour Columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `Date` and an `Hour` column in a PySpark dataframe. How do I merge these together to get the `Desired_Calculated_Result` column?

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('2021-10-20','1300', '2021-10-20 13:00:00.000+0000')
    ,('2021-10-20','1400', '2021-10-20 14:00:00.000+0000')
    ,('2021-10-20','1500', '2021-10-20 15:00:00.000+0000')
  ]
  ,['Date', 'Hour', 'Desired_Calculated_Result']
)
```

I also tried:

```
df1.withColumn("TimeStamp", unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", df1.Date, df1.Hour), "yyyy-MM-dd HHmm").cast("timestamp")).show().
```

This returned all nulls in the Timestamp Column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, unix_timestamp

df1\
  .withColumn("TimeStamp", unix_timestamp(concat(df1.Date, df1.Hour), "yyyy-MM-ddHHmm")\
  .cast("timestamp"))\
  .show()
```

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse &#39;2020-01-01100&#39; in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

Comment: I also tried: df.withColumn("TimeStamp", unix_timestamp(concat_ws(" ", df.Date, df.Hour), "yyyy-MM-dd HHmm").cast("timestamp")).show(). This returned all nulls in the Timestamp Column

Comment: did you try?```spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")```